# Data structure for searching & inserting bitstrings where only "1"s are important

Tags: data-structures

It's hard to explain the problem in pure words, so here's an example of the abstract problem I need to solve:

- In this example, there are entries with the keys "1111","1010","1011","1000","0001" already inserted into the data structure
- I search using the query "1001"
- The query is supposed to return all entries in the data structure where the query has a matching "1" for all "1"s in the key of the entry, but the query may have many more 1s than the compared entries. For this example, the keys "1000" and "0001" should be returned, since the query matches the 1s of those keys. You could say the entries in the data structure "don't care" about the other bits in the query, the entry with the "1000" key only cares that the first bit of the query be 1, and the "0001" key only cares that they last bit be 1.

Some side information/constraints:

- This is optimization for a real-time application, where profiling has shown that improvement in this area would be welcomed.
- The number of entries will be "small" (most likely <500). This means I'm not necessarily looking for best "big O" performance, but rather practical performance on contemporary PC and mobile CPUs and memory. As small memory footprint as possible is a huge bonus, but I strongly suspect this will go hand-in-hand with a well performing solution.
- insertions into the data structure will be very infrequent. Most at startup time of the application, so the structure doesn't have to be optimized for it. But searches will be frequent.
- The values of the entries (key/value pair) in my concrete problem will be arrays of pointers.
- The amount of bits in the numbers is arbitrary, but all keys in the structure and the queries will have the same length. I'm just mentioning this in case there are algorithms which rely on CPU hardware instructions to function efficiently, which would likely only work for 32 bit / 64 bit types. My keys will be longer, but not huge (~128-256 bits).
- I want to specifically mention again that this is for strings of bits, nothing else.
- Queries can have no results as well. For example, in my application, "0000" will never return results, since there are no "1"s to care about.
- Programming language used is C++, compiler is "various compilers", as this is will run on multiple platforms and operating systems

How can I solve this efficiently? Also, are there practical implementations to look at?

Comment: A `*` replaces one bit? You have keys too which contain this don't care? Your key domain is huge (>128bits) but you need a lookup table of only ~500 entries? Will your queries always hit or do you have queries with no result? What about multiple results? Not big-O, then you need to be more specific about the programming environment. Are we talking Java or assembler?

Comment: @Harald Thank you for the questions. * replaces exactly one bit, yes, so * doesn't mean "here are one or more bits that I don't care about". Yes I have keys too which contain this don't care. Yes key domain is relatively big, but table will be small. Queries can have no results, for example, I expect "0000" to never return results. Multiple results, yes, if a query with a wild card matches multiple keys in the data structure, I want them all returned. Programming environment is C++. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Do you have already arepresentation for the keys with wildcard or is this up for design too?

Comment: @Harald This is completely up for design. Right now I don't even have a concept of how a query would specify wildcards. In practice, I have some systems in the application which only care for a specific combination of flags, e.g. system A wants to look for all entries which have the first and third bit activated, so "1*1*" would be the query.

Comment: In the 128 or more bits of a query, will there be typically more wildcards than real bits, or the other way round? What about the keys?

Comment: And to be sure: queries will contain zero bits too, they will not only contain 1 and '*'?

Comment: Typically much more wildcards on the keys, i.e. a typical key will have something like 4 or 5 1s and only wildcards otherwise. Actually, I just thought about the queries, and realized that they don't have to have wildcards. What I really want to do is provide a bit string, and search in the data structures for registered bit strings where all 1s in the keys match some (but not necessarily all) 1s in the query. So in the case of "1**1", I really give "1001" as query and look for all results where the keys have the first and last bit set to 1. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Actually, I may have mis-formulated the problem. I just realized that I never care about the "0", only the "1", which probably has a significant impact on the solution. Give me some minutes to edit the question :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51773/discussion-between-harald-and-travisg)

Comment: How important is space efficiency?

Comment: @templatetypedef Not "very" important. The algorithm shouldn't go full retard (e.g. using several megabytes of memory for such a small amount of entries).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I assume that you have already optimized your query/key comparison code. You should be able to do that efficiently with a bitwise-and plus a compare for each word of the key and query. If you are on an architecture with SIMD instructions, then those can be done in parallel.

You haven't said anything about the meaning of the bits or how you expect them to be distributed among the keys and queries.

If you expect queries to be repeated frequently, one very easy thing you can do is to simply use a linear search with a cache of the n-most frequently used queries.

If most bits of the keys will not be present in the majority of keys, then you could reorder the bits in the keys such that the least frequently occurring bits have the lowest value indexes (i.e bit 0 has the fewest number of keys with that bit set, bit 1 has the next fewest, and so on). Then create an array indexed by bit index whose entries contain the list of keys containing that bit. When resolving queries, pick the lowest set bit in the query (there are bit hacks to do this efficiently), look up the corresponding list of matches and search it linearly. As long as the keys do not have overly dense bit patterns, this should provide a significant speedup.